# How to create a full purchase experience with product advertising api on your website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, amazon-advertising-api

I want to create a store website using amazon's product advertising api, and as I understand, what you actually get from amazon is the products with a shop now button that is taking you to the amazon website to purchase it, something like this:

[image]

but I really wanted to create a full experience in my website, and wanted to know if its possible somehow to mask the purchase and keep the user in my website, does someone know something that can help?

Comment: It seems like even if this were technically possible, it is forbidden.  *(j) You will not modify, redirect, suppress, or substitute the operation of any button, link, or other feature of an Amazon Site.*

*(l) You will not take any action that could reasonably cause any customer confusion as to our relationship with you, or as to the site on which any functions or transactions (for example, search, browse, or order) are occurring.* https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/help/operating/policies

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks buddy, should of read it before i posted the question, appreciate it.